# Source-to-Source transformation with clang (state of the art)

Tags: c++, clang

How is the state of the art in source-to-source transformation with clang?

I followed almost every resource on the Web and I can achieve to do source rewrites (`Rewriter`) via a clang plugin, but the final binary is not updated (the CodeGen is the main activity, and it is compiled regardless of what I have modified in my plugin, even using `AddBeforeMainAction` in the `getActionType`).

I have seen some documents regarding libTooling and how to create an independent program that uses clang as library, but my purpose it is to create a plugin (`FrontendPluginRegistry::Add<>`, something "easy" to plug to a non-custom clang binary) and achieve source-to-source modifications (transparently to the users, avoiding overwriting their source files).

**Edit**: In case it is not clear:
I need something like a "plugin" to extend clang in an easy way. I need something that is "integrated" in the compiling process. Why? because I need to modify the source code during the compilation phase, inject new code, modify the source code from the user in one step (I don't want to create a tool to parse the user source code and then compile the output files). Also, I would like to distribute my code (plugin) to allow users to use it by themselves.

It is mandatory that it is during the compilation phase of clang (`clang $FLAGS $PLUGIN $ETC -o program source_files...`).

Comment: Final binary of what?  Clang?  The program being modified?  Why is this an issue?

Comment: I edit the question. I hope now you understand what I need.

Comment: I see.  You want a runtime plugin to Clang to implement source-to-source transformations as  you compile.   OK, I get it.    I'd expect this to be very hard to do, since the Clang transformation machinery is largely calls on compiled methods in Clang classes, and surely "you" will want to write some kind of source code to realize the transformations which is interpreted at runtime.  Who will intermediate between the source text you write, and the compiled Clang code?  The "mandatory during compilation" seems like an XY problem... why do you insist on that?

Comment: .... FWIW,  DMS's rewrite rules *are* interpreted as they are read, so you could invent new ones on the spot.

Comment: I need something completely open source, well known by the community. DMS doesn't look like. Or am I wrong?

Comment: DMS isn't open source although I think what you mean is "free".   I get the impression the community sort of knows about it, but it is a dark horse.   The community often prefers "free" which I get until they run into limitations.

Comment: In my case I refer as open source (libre). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> the CodeGen is the main activity, and it is compiled regardless of what I have modified in my plugin

Yes, this is because Clang AST is designed to be immutable. You can't change it after parsing.

So state of the art s2s transformation in Clang looks like that:

- Parse C++ source code to AST
- Apply text replacements to original source code, generate new source code
- Parse new source code to create new AST

You can do all steps "in memory", so end user won't notice.

**Update:**
I have never written clang plugins myself. But here is what I've noticed:
If you run Clang fronted to actually generate object code:

```
  clang -cc1 -emit-obj main.c
```

It will run EmitObjAction. EmitObjAction is a FrontEnd Action, so it will parse input source and run codegen. So if you run other FrontEnd actions in parallel, they will have no effect on EmitObjAction. Because each FrontEnd action parses original input source code.

What you can do, is to replace EmitObjAction with your own fork that will do as much of re-parsing as you want.

If you set PluginASTAction::ActionType to ReplaceAction, it should replace built-in Codegen action by your own supplied from plugin.

Comment: Ok, can you show me an example (repo, code) that does this? When I use Rewriter I am modifying the source code in memory, but the Clang AST is not modified. 

Can you elaborate with a "real example", can be as basic as you want, but it has to be a plugin and do it in one step (when the user compiles its source).

Comment: Also, you can guide me how to "trigger" reparsing again after my plugin has finished. @random

Comment: @user3819881 : Did you ever figure out how to trigger the re-parsing?

Comment: Yes, clang AST is designed to be immutable, but you can still make minor modifications in the AST if you are careful enough. CodeGen can be made to run after performing modifications to the AST, so this is actually feasible.